# SoftKeyboard issue when having a textbox inside of a flipview

Tags: xaml, textbox, windows-8.1, soft-keyboard, flipview

I have a TextBox control inside a FlipView control. However, when I press over the TextBox to write in, the windows softkeyboard ends over it.

It's just this small example:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <FlipView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <FlipViewItem>
                <TextBox Text="Pag1" Margin="351,642,438,51"></TextBox>
            </FlipViewItem>
            <FlipViewItem>
                <TextBox Margin="351,642,438,51" Text="Pag2"></TextBox>
            </FlipViewItem>
        </FlipView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

EDIT: It seems that also I can't click anywhere to hide the keyboard!